# Ember.js - classNameBindings is removing classes added from outside

Tags: javascript, ember.js

When Ember recomputes the classes for a component through the `classNameBindings` attribute, it overwrittes any class added *from outside*, for example added by jQuery directly to the element.

Refactoring to get the classes added the "Ember way" through the `classNameBindings` is not an option, since I'm using an external jQuery plugin that adds them, [perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar).

I suppose the problem happens because Ember doen't know about the classes added and just ignores them.

Is there a clean way/workaround for this kind of scenarios?

---

I put up a twiddle with a [minimal working example of the problem here](https://ember-twiddle.com/24fe3f55d791e9aa991f68024b90df73?fileTreeShown=false&numColumns=2&openFiles=components.x-example.js%2Ctemplates.components.x-example.hbs) *(if there is a way to get a working ember example using the code snippets, let me know and I edit)*

Comment: I don't think it will work out smoothly if ember and a custom jQuery plugin should manage the classes of the same element. Did you consider using a child element as container for `perfect-scrollbar`? Another option would be not using `classNameBindings` at all but using an observer to add / remove the class using plain old JavaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restore any DOM state manipulated from outside Ember after Ember rerenders your component.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['component'],
  classNameBindings: [
    'flag:emberClassA:emberClassB'
  ],

  flag: false,

  didRender() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, this.restoreJQueryClass);
  },

  restoreJQueryClass() {
    if (this._savedClassState) {
      this.$().addClass('jQueryClass', this._savedClassValue);
    }
  },

  actions: {
    toggleFlag () {
      this.toggleProperty('flag');
    },
    toggleClassFromOutside() {
      this.$().toggleClass('jQueryClass');
      this.set('_savedClassState', this.$().hasClass('jQueryClass'));
    }
  }
});
```

Generally, most Ember apps today have begun to avoid jQuery and other JavaScript libraries that do DOM manipulation and instead write Ember Components in order to avoid some of the difficulties you are experiencing. Ember itself will soon stop including jQuery by default.

Here is an updated Twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/86ed63a495dbc010a3e7bfb18e2a839a?openFiles=components.x-example.js%2C

This answer is current as of Ember 3.4.